# mysql date add or date sub with variable?

Tags: php, mysql, function

Is it possible to use mysql date add or sub with a variable if I set it.

```
UPDATE table SET time = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL $minutes MINUTES);
```

I have tried but can't get it working?

Thanks

Comment: Is this strictly MySQL or are you using PHP or some other scripting language?

Comment: php, just trying to use mysql a bit more rather than all php

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're using PHP to get the expression part of `DATE_ADD` done right, you're using `MINUTES` rather than `MINUTE`, which is the unit you're looking for:

```
UPDATE table SET time = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL $minutes MINUTE);
```

Also see [the MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

Answer (score 3):

Coming in late to advocate protection from SQL Injection.

```
$qry = 'UPDATE table SET time = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL ' . (int)$minutes . ' MINUTE)';
```

**Note:** Credit to **diEcho** and **fivedigit** for their foundational answers.

Answer (score 2):

TRY

```
$qry = "UPDATE table SET time = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL ".$minutes." MINUTE) ";
```